# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '25' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I want to add multiple tags in mysql database table , in this case when try to add single tag then it's alright but when try to insert multiple tags show this types of error . Here is my migration and storing code .

```
public function store(CreateArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article = Auth::user()->articles()->create($request->all());

    $article->tags()->attach($request->input('tags'));

    flash()->overlay('Your articles has been created!', 'Good Job');
    return redirect('articles');
}
```

Here is migration code :

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('tags',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('articles_tag',function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('articles_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('articles_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is Form code Tag selecting box for  in blade :

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('tags','Tags:') !!}
     {!! Form::select('tags[]',$tags,null,['class'=>'form-      control','multiple']) !!}
```

Comment: Could you paste the whole error you're getting, the tags() method of your model and the value of $request->input('tags')?

Answer (score 1):

Your migration is wrong. The table `articles_tag` is a pivot table, so you can't use increments for the `articles_id` column in that table.

To solve this, replace this line:

```
$table->increments('articles_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

with this one:

```
$table->integer('articles_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

Comment: Ouch, I had the same issue. Thanks ... What a stupid.